# Calculating Euclidean distance in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, euclidean-distance

I have an exe which return an array of 16elements.I have to pass this array to Mysql using php to calculate the Euclidean distance.My table in MySQL is in the form.

```
id |img_id | features_1|features_2|features_3|features_4|features_5|features_6|features_7|...upto features_16
 1   1        0.389       0.4567     0.8981      0.2345
 2   2        0.9878      0.4567     0.56122     0.4532        
 3   3        
 4   4        
 ......................
```

So I have 16 features for each image and now I have 30,000 images that is img_id is upto 30,000. I have to calculate the euclidean distance of the array from exe which is passed through php with the datas in the database and return the img_id of the 6 images whose euclidean distance is minimum.

i.e. Suppose I have an array from exe `A[0.458,0.234,0.4567,0.2398]` I have to compute distance of each img_id with this array i.e for img_id=1 the distance will be `((0.458-0.389)^2+(0.234-0.4567)^2+(0.4567-0.8981)^2+(0.2398-0.2345)^2)` and I have to repeat this process for all the 30,000 images and return the 6 img_id who has least distance. I wrote the following stored proc but it only returns img_id NULL.

if there is any fast way to perform this please mention it.

```sql
create procedure sp_euclideandistance(feature1 double,feature2 double,feature3 double,feature4 double,feature5 double,feature6 double,feature7 double,feature8 double,feature9 double,feature10 double,feature11 double,feature12 double,feature13 double,feature14 double,feature15 double,feature16 double)
 Begin
  Declare i int;
  Declare distance double;
  Declare img_id int;
  Declare features_1 double;
  Declare features_2 double;
  Declare features_3 double;
  Declare features_4 double;
  Declare features_5 double;
  Declare features_6 double;
  Declare features_7 double;
  Declare features_8 double;
  Declare features_9 double;
  Declare features_10 double;
  Declare features_11 double;
  Declare features_12 double;
  Declare features_13 double;
  Declare features_14 double;
  Declare features_15 double;
  Declare features_16 double;
  Set i=92303;
  Set distance=0.000;

  create temporary table temptbl_dist(img_id int,distance int);

  while(i<124232)
  do

    select img_id,features_1,features_2,features_3,features_4,features_5,features_6,features_7,features_8,features_9,features_10,features_11,features_12,features_13,features_14,features_15,features_16 INTO img_id,features_1,features_2,features_3,features_4,features_5,features_6,features_7,features_8,features_9,features_10,features_11,features_12,features_13,features_14,features_15,features_16  from tbl_features where img_id=i;

    Set distance=((feature1-features_1)^2)+((feature2-features_2)^2)+((feature3-features_3)^2)+((feature4-features_4)^2)+((feature5-features_5)^2)+((feature6-features_6)^2)+((feature7-features_7)^2)+((feature8-features_8)^2)+((feature9-features_9)^2)+((feature10-features_10)^2)+((feature11-features_11)^2)+((feature12-features_12)^2)+((feature13-features_13)^2)+((feature14-features_14)^2)+((feature15-features_15)^2)+((feature16-features_16)^2);

    insert into temptbl_dist values (i,distance);

    Set i=i+1;


  end while;
  select img_id from temptbl_dist order by distance asc limit 6;
  drop table temptbl_dist;

End
```

Comment: Any particular reason for the `php` tag?

Comment: Yes if this same process can be done in php will it be faster?

Comment: I doubt if PHP can be faster - you still need to compute and sort, and sorting data is one of the main job for database softwares.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MySQL, but can you reduce your procedure to simply `SELECT img_id FROM (SELECT img_id,((feature1-feature_1^2)+...) "distance" FROM feature_tbl WHERE img_id>=92303 AND img_id<124232) ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 6`?

Comment: I dont think so we can do this.

Comment: SQL Error (1690): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(((((((((((((0.44666 - `fashion`.`tbl_features`.`features_1`) ^ 2) + ((0.89222 - `fashion`.`tbl_features`.`features_2`) ^ 2)) + ((0.44443 - `fashion`.`tbl_features`.`features_3`) ^ 2)) + ((0.9812 - `fashion`.`tbl_features`.`features_4`) ^ 2)) + ((0.0012 - `fashion`.`tbl_features`.`features_5`) ^ 2)) + ((0.1234 - `fashion`.`tbl_features`.`features_6`) ^ 2)) + ((0.3592 - `fashion`.`tbl_features`.`features_7`) ^ 2)) + ((0.9977 - `fashion`.`tbl_features`.`features_8`)  */